# not working ui datepicker and dropdown checklist in one page

Tags: jquery

I have implemented jquery ui date picker colander in my web page. It’s working well. Then I have implemented jquery dropdown checkList. Then my calendar is not Woking

i have implemented Jquery for the calendar is jquery 1.7.1.min  and 
jquery for the dropdown checklist is jquery.js

I need to implement both these in one page

But it's not working
  Anyone know this s
Please help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: why are  you adding two seperate jquery library?

Comment: You cannot have two jquery.js files in your page, they will conflict. Only one version of jQuery per website; it will never work *as intended* with two jQuery versions. Thussly, figure out which one needs newer support, jQuery is backwards compatible *for the most part*.

Answer (score 0):

I think your jquery dropdown call function syntax would be wrong. because if is there any syntax error then also calendar will not be working. 
so First check the perfect syntax.